# IBM Cloud Object Storage: Unable to create a bucket

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage, cloud-object-storage

I am unable to create a bucket on my IBM Cloud Object Storage (COS) instance. Each time I try the "create bucket" in the console, it is always blank (gray) with an error sign hovering over it.

I have tried creating a new instance but an error message says that this account is already on a Lite plan (BMCOSUI090200).

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Your question is missing details. It seems like something for the IBM Cloud support. In general, make sure that you are logged in, cookies enabled, on a supported browser. Have you tried using the command line tool "ibmcloud"? Does it give the same error?

Comment: Yes, I have. Nothing seems to be working

Comment: I have reached out to the support team on several occasions, followed the instructions they gave me but I'm still stuck plus their policy says it doesn't guarantee  proper customer service except one is paying for their cloud services.

Answer (score 1):

An account is limited to a single instance of IBM Cloud Object Storage that uses a Lite plan.

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-faq#faq-instance-find-lite

Your current default is selected as lite; change to standard plan should fix it.

Sven S

Comment: I am currently enrolled in the IBM full stack software developer course and a lite plan is meant to be part of it, i shouldn't have to pay for such upgrade

Comment: See this overview for account types: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-accounts Lite account are not offered anymore, only Trial accounts. You can use free services if you upgraded to a PAYGO account. See https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-accounts#liteaccount